php_redis.dll not working in windows system
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.2.18/ext/redis (The specified module could not be found), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.2.18/ext/php_redis.dll (The specified procedure could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
Launch WampServer from the Start menu or by clicking on its icon in the taskbar.
Switch PHP Version: Once WampServer is running, left-click on its icon in the taskbar to open the menu. Then navigate to PHP > Version and select the desired PHP version from the list. Choose version 7.3 from the available options.
Restart All Services: After selecting the PHP version, WampServer will automatically restart all services to apply the changes. Wait for the restart process to complete.
Verify PHP Version but recived
this error
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis' (tried: c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.2.18/ext/redis (The specified module could not be found), c:/wamp64/bin/php/php8.2.18/ext/php_redis.dll (The specified procedure could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

Does WampServer bundle the Redis extension or you got it from somewhere else?

I don't think you can use php_redis.dll of php8.2.18 in php7.3

Does this answer your question? Redis.dll not found for php8.2
